# KDE session cannot start on kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kernel, asus

I run an Asus laptop on kubuntu 15.10. It has been working fine (except that boot time was very long with no clear explanation), and since yesterday, I can no longer initiate a kde session. I enter my login and password, and after a few seconds, I am sent back to the login screen.

Here is a trace in the syslog:

```
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714189] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714200] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 50 at /build/linux-AFqQDb/linux-4.2.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:12328 check_crtc_state+0x2c5/0x440 [i915]()
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714200] pipe state doesn't match!
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714222] Modules linked in: cdc_ether usbnet mii xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack nf_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp bridge stp llc ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables bbswitch(OE) binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 arc4 asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi nvidia(POE) intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp iwlmvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul aesni_intel mac80211 aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_codec_hdmi input_leds joydev uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc serio_raw videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev iwlwifi media snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_rt5640 snd_soc_rl6231 lpc_ich snd_hda_intel cfg80211 snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec snd_compress snd_hda_core ac97_bus snd_hwdep snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_seq_midi hid_multitouch snd_seq_midi_event snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_me snd_seq mei kvm_intel kvm wmi dw_dmac dw_dmac_core snd_seq_device snd_timer int3402_thermal snd_soc_sst_acpi snd int3400_thermal 8250_dw acpi_thermal_rel acpi_als soundcore kfifo_buf processor_thermal_device i2c_designware_platform int340x_thermal_zone industrialio i2c_designware_core mac_hid intel_soc_dts_iosf spi_pxa2xx_platform intel_smartconnect iosf_mbi parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid psmouse i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper ahci drm libahci video sdhci_acpi sdhci i2c_hid hid
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714242] CPU: 0 PID: 50 Comm: kworker/0:1 Tainted: P        W  OE   4.2.0-23-generic #28-Ubuntu
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714243] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. UX303LN/UX303LN, BIOS UX303LN.204 09/01/2014
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714247] Workqueue: events console_callback
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714248]  0000000000000000 000000008fefa895 ffff880224ea3658 ffffffff817e94c9
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714249]  0000000000000000 ffff880224ea36b0 ffff880224ea3698 ffffffff8107b3d6
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714250]  ffff880224ea36d8 ffff880224ea3740 ffff880225783800 0000000000000001
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714250] Call Trace:
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714254]  [<ffffffff817e94c9>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714258]  [<ffffffff8107b3d6>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714259]  [<ffffffff8107b465>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714268]  [<ffffffffc0199941>] ? intel_pipe_config_compare+0xb31/0xc60 [i915]
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714276]  [<ffffffffc0199d35>] check_crtc_state+0x2c5/0x440 [i915]
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714287]  [<ffffffffc01adb5d>] intel_modeset_check_state+0x21d/0x6d0 [i915]
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714296]  [<ffffffffc01aed17>] intel_crtc_set_config+0x4c7/0x580 [i915]
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714306]  [<ffffffffc00ae4a6>] drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x66/0x100 [drm]
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714311]  [<ffffffffc01252a5>] drm_fb_helper_pan_display+0x95/0xe0 [drm_kms_helper]
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714313]  [<ffffffff81442ead>] ? soft_cursor+0x1ad/0x230
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714322]  [<ffffffffc01bc0ea>] intel_fbdev_pan_display+0x1a/0x60 [i915]
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714324]  [<ffffffff81447e0f>] fb_pan_display+0xcf/0x160
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714326]  [<ffffffff81441f40>] bit_update_start+0x20/0x50
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714327]  [<ffffffff8143f003>] fbcon_switch+0x3b3/0x650
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714328]  [<ffffffff814d28dc>] redraw_screen+0x1ac/0x2a0
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714330]  [<ffffffff814c8cd3>] complete_change_console+0x43/0xe0
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714331]  [<ffffffff814ca4c9>] change_console+0x59/0xa0
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714332]  [<ffffffff814d4ef0>] console_callback+0x110/0x180
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714335]  [<ffffffff810941ca>] process_one_work+0x1aa/0x440
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714336]  [<ffffffff810944ab>] worker_thread+0x4b/0x4c0
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714337]  [<ffffffff81094460>] ? process_one_work+0x440/0x440
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714339]  [<ffffffff81094460>] ? process_one_work+0x440/0x440
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714341]  [<ffffffff8109a868>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714342]  [<ffffffff8109a790>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1f0/0x1f0
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714343]  [<ffffffff817f06df>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714344]  [<ffffffff8109a790>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1f0/0x1f0
Mar  9 22:05:32 pcl-asus kernel: [  401.714345] ---[ end trace 2dd4952a90a8cb1e ]---
```

I can also see another log message, but I do not know if it is relevant:

```
Mar  9 22:05:41 pcl-asus systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6b3f9aba\x2d7e64\x2d4009\x2db7f2\x2d00efb8bbe8e9.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6b3f9aba\x2d7e64\x2d4009\x2db7f2\x2d00efb8bbe8e9.device/start timed out.
Mar  9 22:05:41 pcl-asus systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6b3f9aba\x2d7e64\x2d4009\x2db7f2\x2d00efb8bbe8e9.device.
Mar  9 22:05:41 pcl-asus systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/6b3f9aba-7e64-4009-b7f2-00efb8bbe8e9.
Mar  9 22:05:41 pcl-asus systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6b3f9aba\x2d7e64\x2d4009\x2db7f2\x2d00efb8bbe8e9.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6b3f9aba\x2d7e64\x2d4009\x2db7f2\x2d00efb8bbe8e9.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar  9 22:05:41 pcl-asus systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6b3f9aba\x2d7e64\x2d4009\x2db7f2\x2d00efb8bbe8e9.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6b3f9aba\x2d7e64\x2d4009\x2db7f2\x2d00efb8bbe8e9.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Can anyone please help me to fix my issue?

Comment: I have tried updating my kernel to 4.3, but it did not solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment: the root cause is indeed the same. .Xauthority file was owned by root, and I had to change the owner to solve my issue.

With more details, I performed:
chown user:group ~/.Xauthority
where user is my user name, and group my default group